# Symmetric DS different PK but same unique resolution

Tags: mysql, unique-key, symmetricds

We have this MySQL table:

```
id BINARY PRIMARY KEY, -- this is actually GUID
position INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
some_value VARCHAR(200)
```

On each of two nodes, users create a new entry but with the same position:

```
id=0x01
position=5
some_value = "first node entry"

id=0x02
position=5
some_value = "second node entry"
```

I want to sync this by unique key and not by PK.

How can I do that?

Either of these two entries is accepted as the final result. The question is only about how to set up SymmetricDS to sync in this case.

Comment: Please clarify your requirement and post what you have done so far.

Comment: The setup/confog/code for your symmetricds, as an example.

Answer (score 1):

It was enough to `set sync_key_names="position"` in table sym_trigger.